# LDAP user account with no password (Linux)

Tags: linux, ldap

Is it possible to setup a password-less ldap user login?  I'd like to create a user that runs batch jobs with sudo rights.  So it can ssh to multiple machines and run jobs without using ssh-keygen, and only root has rights to modify it.  This way I don't need to expose root password or expose root ssh on multiple machines.  I could achieve this using local created logins.  Is it possible I can create this in LDAP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if this was possible, it is a horrible idea.

Just use key authentication. That is *the* canonical way to allow programmatic access via ssh from one system to another.

Comment: thanks for the reply. On first thought, it wasn't such a bad idea.  But I guess ssh-keygen does allow another level of restrictions on a system to protect misuse...

Comment: Right, and it's not brute-forcible.